# How to display two p:datable horizontally in an h:form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two p:datable in h:form, the form displays it vertically automatically like this :

[image]

I want them to be displayed horizontally one next to the other

this the code source of the jsf page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="/templates/agent/template_agent.xhtml" >
    <f:facet name="header">

        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jsfcrud.css"/>

    </f:facet>
    <ui:define name="content" >    
        <h:form >

            <p:dataTable style="width: 40%" >

                 <!-- content of the first datatable -->

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dataTable style="width: 60%">

                 <!-- content of the seconde datatable -->

              </p:dataTable>
         </h:form>
    </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the use of  `h:panelGrid` it have a attribute `columns`(Number of columns in the table) which can be use to display different component in column wise

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <p:dataTable />
  <p:dataTable  />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I prefer to use css for this...